# Redirect 302 does not work when I pass it from express to react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, axios

I have an Express Application and in my API, I send a 302 status to the client. The client uses React and AXIOS. It throws this error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://sandbox.zarinpal.com/pg/StartPay/000000000000000000000000000000012807' (redirected from 'http://localhost:5000/api/payment/x/handle/accepted') 
from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

Here is my API

```
router.post('/x/handle/accepted', (req, res) => {
    const uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4');
    zarinpalLib.request(req.body.acamount, req.body.acemail, req.body.acphone, req.body.acdescription, uuidv4(), function (data) {
        if (data.status) {
            console.log('here ', data.url)
            res.writeHeader(302, { 'Location': data.url });
            res.end();
        } else {
            console.log('here2 ', data.code)
            // res.render('error', {zpTitle: appConfig.appTitle, zpError: data.code});
            res.status(500).send(data.code)
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the React part

```
if (inputValue === 'RLS') {
    var data = {
        acfirstname: 'xx',
        aclastname: 'xx',
        acemail: 'xx',
        acphone: phoneNumber,
        acamount: inputAmount,
        acdescription: 'xx'
    };

    const res = await;
    axios({ method: 'POST', url: `${END_POINT_URL}/api/payment/x/handle/accepted`, data });
    console.log(res)
}
```

I use this middleware in my Express app for CORS:

```
var allowCrossDomain = function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,x-phone-token,Location');

    next();
}
```

Comment: The CORS issue is because you're redirecting to `https://sandbox.zarinpal.com/`, which doesn't send a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header. The solution is to make the request from your backend, using node's `http` module (or axios, or node-fetch), then send the result to the client.

Comment: @ChrisG can you provide some code sample with axios?

Comment: Sure: `axios.get(url).then(response => { ... });` You are using it on the client-side. It works the same on the server.